# Navigator.of(context) is not navigating, giving null value error on context

Tags: flutter, google-signin, stack-navigator

Google signin provider class is not navigating to the next screen. Signin the user works, but the suer has to signin then leave the app and then re-open. After re-opening the app works fine with the user signed in.

Error log gives:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value E/flutter ( 9884): #0      StatefulElement.state (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4789:44) E/flutter ( 9884): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2730:47) E/flutter ( 9884): #2      GoogleSignInProvider.signInwithGoogle (package:blahblah/google_signin_provider.dart:37:17) E/flutter ( 9884): <asynchronous suspension>`

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

 Future<String> signInwithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {

  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
    throw e;
  }

  final User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String uid = currentUser.uid;
  if (currentUser != null)
    await usersRef.doc(currentUser.uid).set({'id': uid, 'email': 
 currentUser.email,
      'username': currentUser.displayName, 'photoUrl': 
 currentUser.photoURL,
      'phone': '', 'dob': '', 'sex': ''});

 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TabScreen()));
  notifyListeners();
return null;
}

Future logout() async {
await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
}
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're facing an issue, that is so silly, you'll laugh at yourself after knowing the cause of the error (take it as sarcasm).

The main point here is, we use `context` to refer to our class's reference or location inside the widget tree. So, pointing the wrong `context` will always be error-prone. What you need to do is to point to the accurate `context` variable to navigate properly.

I will suggest you rename all the `context` variables, so you'll know which exact `context` you're using to navigate. What you need to do is to pass the root `context` variable that was provided to your state-full/less widget's build function.

See the example below:

```
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
        builder: (themeBuilderContext, state) {
          final ThemeHelper theme = ThemeHelper(state.theme, false);
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: theme.accentColor),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              title: Text("Authentication", style: TextStyles.title(context: context, color: theme.accentColor)),
            ),
            body: KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
              builder: (keyboardVisibilityContext, isKeyboardVisible) {
                return BlocConsumer<CheckExistenceCubit, CheckExistenceState>(
                  listener: (checkExistenceListenerContext, state){
                    if(state is CheckExistenceSuccess) {
                      if(state.facebookSignIn || state.googleSignIn) {

                        final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {
                          "shouldGoBack": widget.shouldGoBack,
                          "email": state.userId,
                          "first_name": state.firstName,
                          "last_name": state.lastName,
                          "profile_picture": state.profilePicture,
                          "facebook_sign_in": state.facebookSignIn,
                          "google_sign_in": state.googleSignIn,
                        };
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(AppRouter.signUp, arguments: arguments);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  builder: (CheckExistenceBuilderContext, state) {
                    if (state is CheckExistenceError) {
                      return AuthenticationForm(shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack);
                    } else if (state is CheckExistenceNetworking) {
                      return AuthenticationForm(shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack);
                    } else if (state is CheckExistenceSuccess) {
                      if (state.newUser) {
                        if (state.emailSignIn) {
                          return MultiBlocProvider(
                            providers: [
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => VerifyOtpCubit()),
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ResendOtpCubit()),
                            ],
                            child: EmailOTPVerificationWidget(email: state.userId, otpLogId: state.otpLogId, shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack),
                          );
                        } else if (state.phoneSignIn) {
                          return MultiBlocProvider(
                            providers: [
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => VerifyOtpCubit()),
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ResendOtpCubit()),
                            ],
                            child: PhoneOTPVerificationWidget(phone: state.userId, otpLogId: state.otpLogId, shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return MultiBlocProvider(
                            providers: [
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => VerifyOtpCubit()),
                              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ResendOtpCubit()),
                            ],
                            child: EmailOTPVerificationWidget(email: state.userId, otpLogId: state.otpLogId, shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack),
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        return AuthenticationSignInWidget(
                          userId: state.userId,
                          shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack,
                          email: state.emailSignIn,
                          phone: state.phoneSignIn,
                          facebook: state.facebookSignIn,
                          google: state.googleSignIn,
                          firstName: state.firstName,
                          lastName: state.lastName,
                          profilePicture: state.profilePicture,
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      return AuthenticationForm(shouldGoBack: widget.shouldGoBack);
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, look very carefully. I have named my `context` variables differently, except the root one.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Then, I renamed my BlocBuilder's context as the Cubit's name.

```
child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
      builder: (themeBuilderContext, state) {
```

And, here also,

```
body: KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
              builder: (keyboardVisibilityContext, isKeyboardVisible) {
                return BlocConsumer<CheckExistenceCubit, CheckExistenceState>(
                  listener: (checkExistenceListenerContext, state){
```

Look how carefully I renamed all my `context` variables according to their scope. People always overlook small details like this one, I was one of them until I faced the same just like you. Ask me a question, if this doesn't help you out.

Here is a [reference](https://youtu.be/THCkkQ-V1-8?t=8049) for an in-depth explanation.

Now, what you actually need to do is to pass the root `context` variable to your `signInwithGoogle` method.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question because you didn't try to fix the author's code, but I like your answer and learned something new, so +1

Answer (score 0):

Define a navigator key that accesses from everywhere in-app  and pass it to root MaterialApp navigator key property in build method

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

then :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
              navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        //...
    );
}
```

then you should pass navigator navigatorKey.currentContext to your Navigator.of(context) like this:

```
Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TabScreen()));
```

Hope this work's

Comment: thank you, Mojtaba! but, it does not work. same error and no navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening due to your widget getting out of context and not in the widgetry path.  Try and use Builder to see if it resolves your issue